# Learning WebDevelopment with Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring

I am looking to learn Web Development with Spring 3.x and also looking at integrating hibernate into it. What is the best resource for learning Web Development with Spring MVC and Hibernate? I am new to this, so would like some resource that takes me from the ground up. Also recommend the best IDE for this.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a project with spring ROO, it will setup all the best practices for you.

Also, use spring STS IDE, it comes with a few eclipse plugins already installed.

Comment: yes, but roo hides a lot of stuff from you.  you're not really learning how to use spring nearly as much.  I would start with a hand written program first, and once you understand, move on to roo if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Spring in Action is a good book to get started: [http://www.amazon.com/Spring-Action-Craig-Walls/dp/1935182358](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182358)

It covers MVC and Hibernate in short and concise chapters to give you a quick start. For IDEs, I would recommend Eclipse with the Spring IDE plugin installed.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

It depends a little bit on what you mean by " I am new to this". New to web development in general? ... new to java in general or just new to Spring and Hibernate? Spring Roo might be a great tool in general, but in terms of learning you're better off rolling as much as possible by hand. At least in the beginning. That's because it will take you to places where you WILL learn. Things will break, produce weird results, etc., all in all you'll get to know how everything jells. Hibernate in and of by itself can be an adventure. So for starters I'd forego the convenience of Roo and get your hands really really dirty.

I'd vote for starting a project and come back for more when you get stuck.

Comment: New to Spring and Hibernate. 5 Years experience in Struts and JSF.

Comment: Very cool, I'd still roll something by hand for the first one though.